# What does "1/4 turn waterless ceramic disc valve" mean -- will the handle only turn 1/4 way?

Tags: plumbing

I am purchasing a replacement faucet/spout a for very old (1940s) kitchen sink with a curved backsplash. The backsplash limits the turn space of the faucet handles -- they may bump into the back at a full turn.

Since the specifications include the  statement "1/4 turn washerless ceramic disc value cartridge" would that mean the handles only need to move 1/4 turn?  If so, I can use the longer handles, otherwise not.

Comment: I don't know exactly which faucet you are looking at (or where you backslash may be in the way) but usually the faucets turn "forward" so they go from being parallel to the back wall to being pointing at the sink (perpendicular to the wall).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, 1/4 turn valves are inline=on, perpendicular=off, no multiple turns needed.